# excel I need formula in column name "FEBRUARY"

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I have a set of data as below.

**SHEET 1**

```
                +------+-------+
                |    JANUARY   |
                +------+-------+
+----+----------+------+-------+
| ID | NAME     |COUNT | PRICE |
+----+----------+------+-------+
| 1  |  ALFRED  |  11  |  150  |
| 2  |  ARIS    |  22  |  120  |
| 3  |  JOHN    |  33  |  170  |
| 4  |  CHRIS   |  22  |  190  |
| 5  |  JOE     |  55  |  120  |
| 6  |  ACE     |  11  |  200  |
+----+----------+------+-------+
```

**SHEET2**

```
+----+----------+------+-------+
| ID | NAME     |COUNT | PRICE |
+----+----------+------+-------+
| 1  |  CHRIS   |  13  |  123  |
| 2  |  ACE     |  26  |  165  |
| 3  |  JOE     |  39  |  178  |
| 4  |  ALFRED  |  21  |  198  |
| 5  |  JOHN    |  58  |  112  |
| 6  |  ARIS    |  11  |  200  |
+----+----------+------+-------+
```

The RESULT should look like this in sheet1 :

```
                +------+-------++------+-------+
                |    JANUARY   |   FEBRUARY    |
                +------+-------++------+-------+
+----+----------+------+-------++-------+-------+
| ID | NAME     |COUNT | PRICE || COUNT | PRICE |
+----+----------+------+-------++-------+-------+
| 1  |  ALFRED  |  11  |  150  ||  21   |  198  |       
| 2  |  ARIS    |  22  |  120  ||  11   |  200  |       
| 3  |  JOHN    |  33  |  170  ||  58   |  112  |       
| 4  |  CHRIS   |  22  |  190  ||  13   |  123  |       
| 5  |  JOE     |  55  |  120  ||  39   |  178  |       
| 6  |  ACE     |  11  |  200  ||  26   |  165  |         
+----+----------+------+-------++-------+-------+
```

I need formula in column name "FEBRUARY". this formula will find its match in sheet 2

Comment: a `vlookup` will do this.

Comment: how vlookup works here? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the first Count value should go in cell E3 of Sheet1, the following formula would be the usual way of doing it:-

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!C:C,MATCH($B3,Sheet2!$B:$B,0))
```

Then the Price (in F3) would be given by

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!D:D,MATCH($B3,Sheet2!$B:$B,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this query will work fine for your requirement

```
SELECT `Sheet1$`.ID,`Sheet1$`.NAME, `Sheet1$`.COUNT AS 'Jan-COUNT',`Sheet1$`.PRICE AS 'Jan-PRICE', `Sheet2$`.COUNT AS 'Feb-COUNT',`Sheet2$`.PRICE AS 'Feb-PRICE'
FROM `C:\Users\Nagendra\Desktop\aaaaa.xlsx`.`Sheet1$` `Sheet1$`, `C:\Users\Nagendra\Desktop\aaaaa.xlsx`.`Sheet2$` `Sheet2$`
WHERE (`Sheet1$`.NAME=`Sheet2$`.NAME)
```

Provide Actual path insted of

```
C:\Users\Nagendra\Desktop\aaaaa.xlsx
```

First you need to know about how to make connection. So refer http://smallbusiness.chron.com/use-sql-statements-ms-excel-41193.html